# Can I use the word "Genkō" to mean "current"?

Tags: word-requests

I'm looking at words apart from "Genzai" that mean "Current" as in "Present moment".

Can I safely use the word "Genkō", or "現行" for that?

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question.  From the sources I found, there weren't many example sentences.  Here are the sources that I used: [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%8F%BE%E8%A1%8C), and [webilo](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%8F%BE%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AE).

Webilo was the most helpful, saying:

> 現在運用している、現在運営している、現在行われている、といった意味の言い回し。「現行」は「現在行われている」といった意味。

My translation:

> Expression with the meaning(s): currently [making use of/applied](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%81%8B%E7%94%A8), currently operated, currently performed. げんこう has the meaning of currently being [performed/executed](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86).

I will not give examples of its usage here since it can get a little bit confusing for beginners.  Suffice it to say that you will be mostly fluent before you will really encounter it in conversations.

現行｛げんこう｝ is definitely not your best fit for "present moment." I would use the word [現在｛げんざい｝](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8) instead.  It is literally translated as `now;current;present;present time`. Genzai is a lot more commonly used as well.